# create class at runtime for properties in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have dictionary of properties and type as :

---

```
string className = "Class1";
```

---

```
var props = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {
    { "Title", typeof(string) },
    { "Text", typeof(string) },
    { "Active", typeof(bool) }
};
```

I want create class1 at runtime instead of hard coding:
currently I have defined class1 as:

```
public class Class1
{
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public string Text{ get; set; }
        public bool Active{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you use a dynamic? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: Have a look at `ExpandoObject`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Dynamic and expando will not work on xamarin iOS devices

Comment: if you can't use dynamic, then just use a Dictionary<string,object> and store your properties in there.

Comment: If you are targetting iOS, dynamic code generation is not supported since the code has to be compiled AOT. Have a look at this: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/#No_Dynamic_Code_Generation

Comment: I want to create metadata for class and fetch data from SQLite in it .and use it as a item source for binding list or grid.

Comment: When i assign dynamic class(used DynamicObject ) list object as  itemsource to list or grid it is not displaying data